# Java 17 java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException with new InitialContext()

Tags: java, jms

I was having a client to put messages on a JMS queue in Java 8 using the following code. I anonymized the code a bit.

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, JAXBException  {
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "xxxxx" );
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryIn = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup("jms/xxxxxxxxx");
        Destination destinationIn = (Destination)initialContext.lookup("jms/xxxxx");
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryOut = (ConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup("jms/xxxxxxxxxx");
        Destination destinationOut = (Destination)initialContext.lookup("jms/xxxxxxx");
```

Now when upgrading to Java 17 I get an error at

```java
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
```

The error says:

```
<Fri Oct 06 12:05:30 CEST 2023> <Debug> <RJVM> <WL-000517> <'java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultDataEnd' field not initialized
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private boolean java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultDataEnd accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @1bce4f0a
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.getField(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:135)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.<clinit>(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:89)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.getInputStream(ConnectionManager.java:2005)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.dispatch(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:555)
    at weblogic.rjvm.t3.client.MuxableSocketT3.dispatch(MuxableSocketT3.java:180)
    at weblogic.socket.BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.dispatch(BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.java:397)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:981)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:907)
    at weblogic.socket.JavaSocketMuxer.processSockets(JavaSocketMuxer.java:385)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

I tried adding a `module-info.java` with following content to no avail.

```java
module berichtenverkeer-utilities {
    requires java.base;
    requires java.reflect;
    requires java.naming;
    opens java.io;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your version of WebLogic is not compatible with Java 17.

Comment: It is not a weblogic service
I use it as a Jar in JMETER to perform load tests with

Comment: Whatever the situation: you're trying to run some code related to weblogic on Java 17, which is apparently not able to work in that environment. Try to get a newer version of the jar, as the problem has likely since been fixed.

Comment: The fact the stacktrace contains classes with the weblogic prefix do suggest you're using something from WebLogic